# Perl compile, libgdbm incompatibility

Tags: linux, perl, compilation

I'm trying to compile Perl (any version) on a Linux RHEL 6.8 system. Whether I compile manually or use perlbrew, the result is the same. It dies when encountering the libgdbm.so.2.0.0 file.

Here is the tail of the transcript:

Checking your choice of C compiler and flags for coherency...
I've tried to compile and run the following simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { printf("Ok\n"); return(0); }

I used the command:

        cc -o try -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib try.c -lnsl -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lut
il -lc
         ./try

and I got the following output:

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../libgdbm.so when searching for -lgdbm
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgdbm.so when searching for -lgdbm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdbm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
I can't compile the test program.
(The supplied flags or libraries might be incorrect.)

You have a BIG problem.  Shall I abort Configure [y]
Ok.  Stopping Configure.
```

Any ideas? I don't think that version of libgdbm is old.

Comment: What commands did you run? Which versions of perl did you try?

Comment: Perl 5.24 and 5.18. Manually I try compiling by typing "./Configure", or if I use perlbrew it is the same. Example: perlbrew install perl-5.18.2

Comment: When I ask the Configure tool to use gcc instead of cc, it gives me a slightly different list of "libraries", but ultimately the end is the same, it dies on libgdbm.so.

Comment: This may help you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193864/how-to-fix-skipping-incompatible-usr-lib-libc-a

Comment: Awesome! This is the first that I noticed that my list of libraries includes both 64 bit and 32 (unmarked) versions. I eliminated the non-64 ones and now I'm compiling. Not sure if that is all of my issues, but that is it for this particular detail.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first that I noticed that my list of libraries includes both 64 bit and 32 (unmarked) versions. I eliminated the non-64 ones and now I'm compiling. Not sure if that is all of my issues, but that is it for this particular detail. – Cliff Warren